# Finding trending words in incident system

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that find out "trending" words in error report, and if any word appear more than ... 4 times in all cases 30 days back it should create a new case with data from the "trigger cases".

That I've got now after filtering is :

```
Id    Word     
--    ----     
12345 sub2255  
36651 sub2255
35542 sub2255  
12345 drivrutin
36651 drivrutin
```

What I wont to create is:

```
Word        Id1     Id2     Id3 id.....     
--          ---    ---    ---    
sub2255     12345  36651  35542
drivrutin   12345  36651
```

In some cases the "word" can appear in many times so the columns must expand with the same count of word.

I´m searching for solutions for a while, but can´t find any who solves my problem.

// Obbelix_Swe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this array as input, which is just as example, you should be using the original object you already have with `| Group-Object Word`:

```
$incidents = @'
Id    Word     
12345 sub2255  
36651 sub2255
35542 sub2255  
12345 drivrutin
36651 drivrutin
12333 drivrutin
12344 drivrutin
12355 drivrutin
12366 drivrutin
12345 string
44444 string
55555 string
'@ -replace ' +',',' |
ConvertFrom-Csv | Group-Object Word
```

The code could look something like this:

```
$max = ($incidents | Measure-Object Count -Maximum).Maximum
$headers = 1..$max | ForEach-Object { "ID$_" }

$result = foreach($incident in $incidents)
{
    $out = [ordered]@{}; $i = 0
    $out['Word'] = $incident.Name

    foreach($header in $headers)
    {
        $out[$header] = $incident.Group[$i].ID
        $i++
    }
    
    [pscustomobject]$out
}

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Which results in:

```
Word      ID1   ID2   ID3   ID4   ID5   ID6  
----      ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---  
sub2255   12345 36651 35542                  
drivrutin 12345 36651 12333 12344 12355 12366
string    12345 44444 55555
```

Comment: Works perfectly!
But i´m stuck again :(
I need to figure out an foreach loop for every column like Id* with data.
In a write-host it should be like:
"The word: $word appear in the following incidents: $Incidents"
"The word: Sub2255 appear in the following incidents:12345, 24556, 36651 "

Comment: @Obbelix_SWE That is unrelated to the question posted. You're asking something different now, please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it was helpful and your initial question was answered and ask a new question adding all the details mentioned on your comment.